# Time Different is not working correctly?

Tags: php

i try to get time difference between two time schedules in php but its not working properly.

```
$stime="10:00 pm";
$sptime="11:30 pm";
//convert into 24hr format
$Cstime  = date("H:i:s", strtotime($stime));
$Csptime  = date("H:i:s", strtotime($sptime));

//call the method
$diff=get_time_different($Cstime,$Csptime);

//define method
function get_time_different($Cstime,$Csptime)
{
    $Cstime = strtotime("1/1/1980 $Cstime");
    $Csptime = strtotime("1/1/1980 $Csptime");

    if($Csptime<$Cstime)
    {
        $Csptime = $Csptime+ 86400;
    }

    return($Csptime-$Cstime) / 3600;
}
echo $diff;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
1.5
```

but i need 1.30. what is the problem

Comment: It's correct 1.5 hours = 90 minutes. 30 minutes it's 0.5 hours.

Comment: `return($Csptime-$Cstime) / 60;` to get difference in minutes and it will return 90 min. Your code is correct. .5 means half of the hours.

Comment: thanks frnds i got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code to convert hours to time format,

```
//$diff = 1.5;

$min = $diff*60;
$time = gmdate("H:i", ($min * 60));
echo $time; // output : 01:30
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$stime="10:00 pm";
$sptime="11:30 pm"; 
$time1 = new DateTime(date('H:i:s',strtotime($stime)));
$time2 = new DateTime(date('H:i:s',strtotime($sptime)));
$diff = $time1->diff($time2);
echo $diff->h.'.'.$diff->i;
```

Output:

```
1.30
```

Now, as you can see the variable '$diff' is a object and you have acccess to hours,minutes, seconds..

```
 public 'y' => int 0
 public 'm' => int 0
 public 'd' => int 0
 public 'h' => int 1
 public 'i' => int 30
 public 's' => int 0
 public 'weekday' => int 0
 public 'weekday_behavior' => int 0
 public 'first_last_day_of' => int 0
 public 'invert' => int 0
 public 'days' => int 0
 public 'special_type' => int 0
 public 'special_amount' => int 0
 public 'have_weekday_relative' => int 0
 public 'have_special_relative' => int 0
```